# Django DatetimeField serialization format

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am using ajax to add posts to my template and i wont to get the same datetimefield format as in {post.pub_date} which looks like "Feb. 16,2016 1:13:49 p.m."
On other subject I found something like this:

```
class DjangoOverRideJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
"""
JSONEncoder subclass that knows how to encode date/time and decimal types.
"""
def default(self, o):
    # See "Date Time String Format" in the ECMA-262 specification.
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
        r = o.isoformat(' ')
        if o.microsecond:
            r = r[:23] + r[26:]
        if r.endswith('+00:00'):
            r = r[:-6] + 'Z'
        return r
    elif isinstance(o, datetime.date):
        return o.isoformat(' ')
    elif isinstance(o, datetime.time):
        if is_aware(o):
            raise ValueError("JSON can't represent timezone-aware times.")
        r = o.isoformat(' ')
        if o.microsecond:
            r = r[:12]
        return r
    elif isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
        return str(o)
    else:
        return super(DjangoOverRideJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
```

but i dont know how change it to get wanted format. Any advice will be helpfull.

Comment: format the datetime with strftime, and encode the string

Comment: thanks for advice, it works for me

Comment: Nice! will post is as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the Python datatime object into a string using strftime. Then, encode the string, which works with JSON serialisation, like any other string.

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime